# Issue with scraping from rendered website

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the price of a piece of clothing off this website: http://www.asos.com/asics/asics-gel-kayano-evo-trainers-in-black-h707n-9090/prd/7592389?iid=7592389&clr=Black&cid=4209&pgesize=36&pge=0&totalstyles=2160&gridsize=3&gridrow=2&gridcolumn=1

Here is a [link to a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQi44.png) of page to be scraped.

Using Scrapy shell:

`response.xpath('//span[@data-id="current-price"]/text()').extract()`

does not return anything, even after rendering the website. Any idea how to scrape this piece of price info from the website?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrapy doesn't execute javascript rendering, for that you'll need a browser automation service, like `selenium` or [`splash`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash).

But, in this case, you can still get the information you want from the same original response, as it contains the data (but wasn't rendered on the html tag it finally appears). Most sites get the extra information from separate requests, which leads to a more difficult crawling.

You can get the information you want this way:

```
import json
...

d = json.loads(response.xpath('//script[contains(., "Pages/FullProduct")]/text()').re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',"))
print d['price'] // {u'currency': u'GBP', u'current': 70.0, u'previous': 0.0, u'rrp': 0.0}
print d['price']['current'] // 70.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works very well. If I may, can I ask how `.re_first("view\('(\{.*\})',"))` works? I understand it's using regular expressions

Comment: yes, it is only a handy scrapy method to use regular expressions with the output of the selector